# How to increment alphanumeric column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a table with 8 columns, three of them are

```
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
DATEPOSTED DATE,
SALESNO VARCHAR(15)
```

Now I want `salesno` column to be autoincremented on insert and be in the format

```
MT00000001\15 
MT00000002\15
MT00000003\15
```

where 15 is the last two digits from the year the post was done. And the year should remain 15 for all posts done between July 1, 2014 to June 30, 2015 And again \16 for all posts done between `July 1, 2015 to June 30, 2016 and so on.

Comment: This post does not show any kind of effort on your part. People on SO can help you if you're stuck, not do your job for you.

Comment: When you change year, should the other part of the number continue to increase, or should it start from 00000001 again?

Comment: Zohar: the number part should continue to increase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SALESNO  should be a computed column with the following definition

```
SALESNO AS ('MT'+ RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',8) + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)),8)+'/'+
CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,6,DATEPOSTED)) AS VARCHAR(2))
```

Comment: Suggestion: Use `REPLICATE` for **00000000**. e.g. `REPLICATE('0',8)`

Comment: Hi Madhivanan, I have used your code and it worked except for the two digits of the year. It just shows asterisk (*), as shown on the attached.ID SALESNO DATEPOSTED PRODUCTNAME
1 MT00000001/* 1/2/2010 Product1

Comment: Madhivanan, I have edited your code by removing '(' which is near MT. And also added "% 100' after 'DATEPOSTED))' and it worked perfectly well. Here is the code: SALESNO AS 'MT'+ RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',8) + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)),8) + '/'+ CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,6,DATEPOSTED)) % 100 AS VARCHAR(2))